# How would I make this query in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

```
class Content(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    stamp = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Comments(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content)
    message = models.TextField()
```

I want to get all the comments for content that the current logged in user created. 
But this doesn't work:

```
Comments.objects.filter(content.author = request.user)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [field lookups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Comments.objects.filter(content__author=request.user)
```

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to "follow" relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.